# CSS Syels not apply to multiple controls

Tags: css, asp.net, .net

I am trying to apply a style to multiple of these trackbars.

If I use a period instead of a #. it does not apply the styling at all. Using [#trackBar_MD] only applies to 1 item. How do I apply the style to multiple of the controls.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VerticalSlider.aspx.cs" Inherits="SliderTool.VerticalSlider" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v16.1, Version=16.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">
        .dxeTBHSys.center 
        {
            margin: 60px auto;
        }
        .dxeTBVSys.center 
        {
            margin: auto;
        }

        .trackBar_MD
        {
            background: transparent url("/Content/img/Drag.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            left: 174px; 
            top: -7px;
            width: 50px; 
            height: 16px;
            background-size: 100%;
        }

        .trackBar_T
        {
            background-image:none;
            background-color:black;
        }
        
        .trackBar_S
        {
            background-image:none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div style="float: left; width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 350px">
            <div style="border: thin solid black;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 350px">
                <br /><br />
            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBar" CssClass="center TrackBar_MD" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
                
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>
                            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBa1r" CssClass="center TrackBar_MD" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
                
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>
                            <dx:ASPxTrackBar ID="trackBar2" CssClass="center TrackBar_MD" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="50" Step="1" 
                LargeTickInterval="10" SmallTickFrequency="5" EnableViewState="false">
                
            </dx:ASPxTrackBar>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your CssClass attribute in each <dx:ASPxTrackBar...> is TrackBar which you have not defined in your CSS. Change it to trackBar_MD.

Comment: See how [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) work.

Comment: Change `CssClass="center TrackBar"` to `CssClass="center TrackBar_MD"` or change `.TrackBar_MD` to `.TrackBar`.

Comment: I tried that already. I updated the sample to show it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: CSS is case sensitive, so change CssClass="center TrackBar_MD" to CssClass="center trackBar_MD".

Comment: Kami - Using the Correct casing does apply something.  But the _MD does something to the images. It's now applying the css but not doing what the _MD should do. So the images are all distorted.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are supposed to be unique to one element so anything with a # symbol is an ID. A class is defined by the period. Classes can be applied to many items. Try adding `trackBar_MD` to the `CssClass` on the elements you want styled that way.

Comment: I tried that already. I updated the sample to show it.  Any thoughts?